# Extend Lollipops "heads-up" notification duration

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-notifications, heads-up-notifications

Been trying to find a way to create a persistent heads up notification, exactly like receiving a phone call or hangouts call. Are these restricted to Google/system apps?

I've tried:

- Updating the notification before the heads up notification is removed.
- Setting the ongoing flag to true.
- Setting auto cancel to false

Can't seem to find this being done anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It worked for me:

- set ongoing flag to true
- set full screen intent
- set priority to PRIORITY_HIGH
- set category to CATEGORY_CALL

Comment: I must've missed the setCategory for the builder. Thanks! https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setCategory(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

[Heads-Up Notifications](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Heads-up) (API level 21) :

> Examples of conditions that may trigger heads-up notifications include:
>
> - The user's activity is in fullscreen mode (the app uses fullScreenIntent), ***or***
> - The notification has high priority and uses ringtones or vibrations

Second case was enough for me to show heads-up notification. Here is a sample code:

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("Title")
        .setContentText("Message")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.your_sound))
//        .setOngoing(true)
        .build();

NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
nm.notify(42, notification);
```

Running this sample code every second (depends on your_sound.mp3 duration...) did the trick.

Note, you may want to play silent.mp3 after the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Just, add `setOngoing` to true. `.setOngoing(true);`, that`s how you make the notification (heads up), display longer, also no notification is now unswipeable, in the notification panel.